# Showing the not filtered data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

this question might be a common question and already answered, but I didn't find any precise solution.

I have a tables; "Liste"

the table has only 3 columns: "Customer"(date type), "Product"(date type) and "Product line"(date type).

I want to show Customer names that except the filtered ones. For example, my table look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DT6C.png)

I have a slicer and use Product line as It's field.
and I have a slicer and use Product as It's field.

When I filtered my data as 100 in the fisrt slicer and D in my second slicer
this is the visual in my visual.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvmDz.png)

I want to show the data which is not filtered.
for example when I filter by 100 in the first slicer, it shows all customers that are not 100 in the Product line
like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U5x9.png)

and the second case I would like to show all the customers that are in a specific Product line, but when I select an article from this Product line, it shows me the customers that in this Product line are missing the article.

like this:
--Product line '100' is selected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p87dc.png)

--and Product 'D'

to show:

300192

which has product B and Product line 100, but does not have product 'D'

I created a DAX formula that shows me all Customers that are or not in a selected Product line 'Yes / No' so, when I select an Product line in my slicer and it shows me.

like this :
Slicer -- Product line '100'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOGKY.png)

I did the same with an Article but is not working., because I get all the customers that do not have this article and I would like to show the customers that in this Product line does not have the selected article.